# Getting no grad set error in pytorch while traning

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

`RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

i'm getting this error with the following training loop, the grads must have been set by the sequential itself, but it's saying no grads.

```
"""Training"""
Epochs = 100


for epoch in range(Epochs):
    model.train()

    train_logits = model(X_train)
    train_preds_probs = torch.softmax(train_logits,dim=1).argmax(dim=1).type(torch.float32)
    loss = loss_fn(train_preds_probs,y_train)
    train_accu = accuracy(y_train,train_preds_probs)
    print(train_preds_probs)
    optimiser.zero_grad()

    loss.backward()

    optimiser.step()

    #training
    model.eval()
    with torch.inference_mode():
        test_logits = model(X_test)
        test_preds = torch.softmax(test_logits.type(torch.float32),dim=1).argmax(dim=1)
        test_loss = loss_fn(test_preds,y_train)
        test_acc = accuracy(y_test,test_preds)

    
    if epoch%10 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch:{epoch} | Train loss: {loss} |Taining acc:{train_accu} | Test Loss: {test_loss} | Test accu: {test_acc}')
```

I tried surfing the internet for this, but didn't get a solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make a toy, simple, reproducible example. If it still does not work, post it here. If it works, build upon it, add missing elements and find the root cause of your problem

Comment: Oh!I got it. I tried making the model again and it worked.Thanks for your help, though still i didn't get the reason for that error, maybe the next time i get it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this kind of error is thrown as part of your code is wrapped by a

```
with torch.no_grad():
```

I suggest to check various function in your code checking for it.
Maybe you have already checked it but this is a good start!

Comment: Thanks a lot, figured it out by myself, wrote the model again and it worked.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

`train_preds_probs = torch.softmax(train_logits,dim=1).argmax(dim=1).type(torch.float32)`

When you `argmax`, you lose the gradient chain and can't backprop. For training, you pass the softmax output to your loss function without the argmax.